# Media Player loading media again and again

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am making a chat application and I have implemented the feature for sending audio messages.But here I find one thing which I don't want it to happen.It is that whenever my adapter gets updated,The media player starts loading again. In this way there will be an issue for if someone is listening to an audio and the user at other end sends a message ,the media player stops and it loads again.Here is the code of my adapter.

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            handler = new Handler();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer1 -> {
                    mediaPlayer1.stop();
                    binding.audioSeekbar.setProgress(0);
                });
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(finalUrlToLoad[1]);
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer1 -> {
                    int totalDuration = mediaPlayer1.getDuration();
                    binding.totalDurationAudio.setText(createTimeLabel(totalDuration));
                    binding.loadingAudio.setVisibility(GONE);
                    binding.playPauseAudio.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            binding.playPauseAudio.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    binding.playPauseAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_to_play);
                    Drawable drawable = binding.playPauseAudio.getDrawable();
                    if( drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        AnimatedVectorDrawable animation = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(binding.audioSeekbar.getProgress());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    handler.post(runnable);
                    binding.playPauseAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_to_pause);
                    Drawable drawable = binding.playPauseAudio.getDrawable();
                    if( drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
                        AnimatedVectorDrawable animation = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable;
                        animation.start();
                    }
                }
            });
            runnable = () -> {
                int totalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                binding.audioSeekbar.setMax(totalTime);
                int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                binding.audioSeekbar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                binding.totalDurationAudio.setText(createTimeLabel(totalTime));
                Log.d("time", String.valueOf(currentPosition));
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
            };
            binding.audioSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                    if (b){
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                        seekBar.setProgress(i);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener((mediaPlayer1, i) -> binding.audioSeekbar.setSecondaryProgress(i));
```

Here finalurltoload[1] is the url for the audio.

Now what do I need to do in order to prevent loading it again and again.

I will be really grateful to who answer this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. First extract the media player code into singleton class like AudioManager.
2. Add few method like setMediaUpdateListener that set a callback for  seek duration. and togglePlayPause to play or pause the audio.
3. Passed the message id or any unique identifier to the audio manager while playing the video.

In Adapter class onBind Method.

1. First Compare the id and playing Id is same like AudioManager.getInstance().isPlaying(messageId);
2. If yes then set the seekUpdatelistner to the audio manager class.
   also update the play/pause icon based on AudioManager.isPlaying() method.

3.if user play other message by clicking play button. call AudioManager.play(message) method.In which we release the previous message and play the new one.

4. If current message is not playing then reset the view on non-playing state.
5. If Auto play is enabled then you need to check if audioManager is free then only you can play the last message otherwise ignored.

Like a class who are managing the audio for you and store all the state.

```
class AudioManager {

public static AudioManager instance;
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private AudioListener audioListener;
private Uri currentPlaying;

public AudioManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AudioManager();
    }
}


public void play(Uri dataUri) {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && currentPlaying == null || currentPlaying.equals(dataUri)) {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }

        return;

    } else if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();

    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    handler = new Handler();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer1 -> {
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
            sendProgress(0);
        });
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataUri;
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayer1 -> {

            int totalDuration = mediaPlayer1.getDuration();
            sendTotalDuration(totalDuration);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void pause() {
    // update the pause code.
}

public void sendProgress(int progress) {
    if (audioListener != null) {
        audioListener.onProgress(progress);
    }
}

public void sendTotalDuration(int duration) {
    if (audioListener != null) {
        audioListener.onTotalDuraration(duration);
    }
}

public void AudioListener(AudioListener audioListener) {
    this.audioListener = audioListener;
}

public interface AudioListener {
    void onProgress(int progress);

    void onTotalDuraration(int duration);

    void onAudioPlayed();

    void onAudioPaused():
}
```

}

Comment: `First extract the media player code into singleton class like AudioManager`.I did not get what do you mean by extract the media player code

Comment: And how do I add a singleton class.

Comment: I have added code to demonstrate How you can proceed further

Comment: is` mediaplayer.play` mediaplayer.start

Comment: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmxDM.png` this is giving error.Check the image.

Comment: above code is not a actual implementation, It is a abstract idea to solve a problem

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from this code but I assume this is all set in your onBind event? If so, then this means every time RecyclerView creates a new holder and binds it, the associated media will be prepped and loaded, and whichever is the 'last holder to have been called with onBind, "wins" (and is what MediaPlayer will be loaded with). Since by default RecyclerView typically creates multiple holders up front, you are seeing your MediaPlayer being "loaded" multiple times.

You probably just don't want to do the initialization of each audio message in the onBind. Instead, just use the onBind event to initialize state variables (duration, progress, etc.) to some default value, hide them and bind the specific audio Uri. Then when the user takes some action like tapping on the holder, you unhide an indeterminate progress bar while the initialization takes place, and in the onPrepared() event unhide the state information (duration, progress, seekbar, etc.), and finally hide the indeterminate progress bar and start the audio.

I assume you are also sending over the sound file as part of your messaging app (i.e. not storing it on the web somewhere in a central location?), and this file gets stored in an app-specific storage location? If so, you don't need to worry about persisting the permission to that URI, but if that isn't the case you will.

Comment: the messages are saved on firebase Firestore and audio on firebase Storage.

Comment: Then the Uri you are saving that points to them won't survive a device reboot unless your app persists the permissions associated with opening the Uri in order to be able to access them in the future. And you only get a specific amount of those depending on your API version (128 up to API 9 I believe, 512 after). Here is a good article on it, specifically about playing sounds: https://www.wochstudios.com/persistent-uri-permissions-in-android/